# AngularJS - Get value from combo box/dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to build and easy Signup form and I am using  in my HTML.
I was struggled with getting the picked value from my dropdown option and right now I'm using a static value to assure I pass a value to my DB and create a successful signup action.
My HTML have a big chunk of options and I would like to know if I can put this data inside my controller and still display in inside my HTML as an option? 
and how I can bind the value from my HTML and send it to my server?

HTML:

```
   <header id="top" class="header">
        <div class="text-vertical-center">
            <h1>Tester</h1>
            <h3>The test.</h3>
            <br>
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</a>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h3 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="" method="" class="form-signin" ng-app="signUpCtr" ng-controller="mainController">
                                <input type="text" id="inputName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" required autofocus>
                                <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
                                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus ng-model="email">
                                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required>
<select ng-model="region" ng-options="x for (x,y) in countries" id="inputRegion" class="form-control"></select>

                                <br/>
                                <div class="terms">
                                    <a href="terms.html" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a>
                                </div>
                                <button ng-click="signUp()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="button">Sign Up</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

JS (Controller):

```
var app = angular.module('signUpCtr', [])
var appPath = "https://google.com";

app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$http, $window) {
    $scope.signUp = function(){
        if($scope.name=="")
            return $scope.errorMsg = "Please Enter Valid Name";
        if($scope.password=="")
            return $scope.errorMsg = "Please Enter Valid Password";
        if($scope.email=="")
            return $scope.errorMsg = "Please Enter Valid Email";
        if($scope.region=="")
            return $scope.errorMsg = "Please Enter Region";

    $scope.countries = {
        Afghanistan : "AFG",
        Albania : "ALB",
        Algeria : "DZA",
        Andorra : "AND"
    };

        console.log("User "+$scope.email+" logged in");
        var user = {
            'name': $scope.name,
            'password': $scope.password,
            'email': $scope.email,
            'region': "USA"
        };
        $http.post(''+appPath+'/signUp', user)
            .then(function(data){
            $window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        });
    };
});
```

But with no success, no options is displayed inside the dropdown.

Comment: What problem did you have with your current code ? It seems okay to me. with ng-model on your `select` you get the value of the selected option right into $scope.region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure that you can. Take a look at `ng-options`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

So in your case define your list inside your controller as for example:

```
$scope.countries = ALLMYLIST;
```

As for example:

```
$scope.countries = [{name: 'Italy', value: 'IT'}, {name: 'England', value: 'EN' }];
```

And then just do:

```
<select name="countries" id="inputRegion" ng-model="region">
      <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.value}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

It would be better to move your countries inside a constant if static, or inside a service if you retrieve them from a server.

I hope it helps

Comment: How it is better to get this list of countries ?

Comment: If this list is static, you can put it in a constant and inject the constant inside your controller. Otherwise if this list is dynamic or somehow related to some changes/server code, get it from the server using `$http`. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to put it that way (see the edited post)

Comment: I can't see anymore the select in your HTML. Did you forget to copy my HTML?

Comment: sorry just saw it now

Comment: please copy correctly my code, `$scope.countries` has to be an array as I defined and the HTML should be the one I posted

Comment: then you should move the init of $scope.countries outisde the signUP function, in order to init that variable not only on singup

Comment: The options are invisible, there are rows but it is invisible.

Comment: {{option.name}} - should be country.name .